# Keepassx does not work with Hotmail

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hotmail, keepassx

I am using Keepassx on a Linux computer to manage my passwords.  Most of the time when using auto-type to get my Hotmail password, Keepassx types in a password that is 7 digits to long.

Comment: Are auto-type and Keepassx redundant and both trying to do the same job?  Can you describe the extra characters (some digits repeat, repeat of the entire password, random characters)?

Comment: Thanks fixer1234 the answer is two things are doing the same job Firefox password helper was still on i was thinking it turned of after i modified the hot-mail password but it did not, i could have check it again but i dit not think aboud this

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Keepassx were both filling in a password. Go from the preference to the security Window and chains the passwords settings!